# How to render mathematical symbols dynamically inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want the user to type in for example "3^" and then the cursor moves up to type the power. Another example is to type "sqrt" and then it transforms to a square root symbol that gets bigger dynamically as more characters are typed inside it. And support for writing fractions as well.

Before any one tells me it's impossible to achieve, I just want to point out that it works beautifully in online graphing calculators such as [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and many other web apps, and by inspecting I found they're using the regular old textarea.

Comment: There's a great article written by Desmos on Medium about how they replace typed characters with MathJax live, and use their own **simulated** textarea to actually recreate the effect. I can't seem to find it now, though.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll try searching for it.

Comment: Found it: https://engineering.desmos.com/articles/press-a-key-in-the-calculator/ @AbdelrhmanElmahdy